# Is there a way to write a script to update React function component props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to write a chrome extension to update React components' props. But seems it work well for class component, but doesn't work for function component. any ideas?

Here's sample code:

```
// just add two very simple components
const FunctionComponent = ({ text }) => <div>FunctionComponent: {text}</div>;

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>ClassComponent: {this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <FunctionComponent text="--" />
    <ClassComponent text="--" />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// update props outside of react
function updateProps(domElement, newProps) {
  var keys = Object.keys(domElement);
  var instanceKey = keys.filter((prop) =>
    /__reactInternalInstance/.test(prop)
  )[0];
  var instance = domElement[instanceKey];

  for (var prop in newProps) {
    if (newProps.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      instance.return.stateNode.props[prop] = newProps[prop];
    }
  }
  instance.return.stateNode.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(
    instance.return.stateNode
  );
}

// update ClassComponent: works!
updateProps(document.getElementById("root").childNodes[1], { text: "works!" });

// update FunctionComponent: can't get return.stateNode
updateProps(document.getElementById("root").childNodes[0], { text: "works!" });
```

CodePen: [https://codepen.io/nick511/pen/JjGqaEm](https://codepen.io/nick511/pen/JjGqaEm?editors=1011)

p.s. function updateProps is from:
[Is it possible to write a script to inject props on a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618119/is-it-possible-to-write-a-script-to-inject-props-on-a-react-component)

Comment: The way you're doing it with classes is completely unsupported and will break with future React updates.

Comment: @DanAbramov Thanks for the reply :) Do you have any recommendations? or how does the react dev tools make it work? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031263/is-there-a-way-to-update-react-component-without-using-props