# Is there a way to update react component without using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to update a react component from another component **not connected** to each other via props. How can i?

Comment: Perhaps [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) might help? This allows you to put a context provider near the root, and then gain access to the state or set the state in any child element. It can sometimes be much more convenient than passing through props.

Comment: @David784 that's true. I actually use redux for the implementation

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use state somewhere above the level of both of the components. Then you have to have a method to change that state which then passes the data down via props.

Edit: So, you need to have some sort of state management, either by hooks context or some other state management, like redux, mobx, etc. For quick and dirty, use useContext.

Comment: i didn't want to do that, thats what i'm avoiding

Comment: The only other option is to have state above it with a function that can change it. So, technically, you can do it without useContext but that means that your component must be a class. Hope it helps. Wish I had a better answer for you. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes you can do :

```js
this.forceUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **key** as props and give it an updated value in that.

but, theres a catch.
When key updates, react will recreate that component in the component tree, ie, it will unmount and remount

```
<Component key={some-value-that-updates}/>
```